# PHP to HTML: Manage horizontal list with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I'm creating a horizontal button list with content feed from server. The list breaks to another line when the content overflows.

Each button can have text of random length, so breaking it in certain point won't work. What i want to achieve is the last line of contents to be longer (or at-least equal) to the above list contents
[image]

Php code:

```
<ul class="tab-menu__items">
    <?php if ($related_products): ?>
        <?php foreach ($related_products as $key => $related_product): ?>
            <li class="tab-menu__item">
                <a href="#" class="tab-menu__link">
                    <?php echo $related_product['product_name']; ?>     
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for displaying " last line of contents to be longer (or at-least equal) to the above list contents" first need to sort the array based on the length of array value

```
<ul class="tab-menu__items">
    <?php if ($related_products): ?>
        <?php array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $related_products), $related_products);?>    
        <?php foreach ($related_products as $key => $related_product): ?>
            <li class="tab-menu__item">
                <a href="#" class="tab-menu__link">
                    <?php echo $related_product['product_name']; ?>     
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The logic sounds good. But the related products is a multi dimension array.

Comment: then you can convert multidimension array into the signle dimension for "product_name" using array_column($related_product,'product_name') and then use that array

Comment: I ordered the products by name in the query itself. It worked fine until their were 3 short name products and a single long name product. This caused three products to stack above a single product. However, i solved it by breaking it in every 4th position. Your ans helped a lot Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do it you can write at the second line the same bottom as at the first line just hiding it by changing the color

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Like @poonam's answer I ordered the array by products name. Since the design could arrange max 4 products in a single line. I count the total products and stack them with 4 on each line. If the total products was not multiple of 4, then the remainder number of products was added at the top.

Final Solution:

```
<?php
$total_related_products = count($related_products);
if($total_related_products > 4) {
    $first_break_point = $total_related_products%4;
}
?>

<?php foreach ($related_products as $key => $related_product): ?>
    <li class="tab-menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="tab-menu__link">
            <?php echo $related_product['product_name']; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php
    if($total_related_products > 4 && (($key+1 == $first_break_point) || (($key+1-$first_break_point)%4==0)))
    {
        echo '<br>';
    }
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```